# Notepad++ regex find XML tags which does not contain certain child XML tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to look in notepad++ for XML tags which does not contain a certain child tag. For example you have a lot of XML tags like this:

```
<situation xsi:type="management" id="...">
        ....
        <mobility>
            ...
        </mobility>
        .....
</situation>
```

And some of them do not contain the mobility tag like this:

```
<situation xsi:type="management" id="...">
        ....
</situation>
```

For the one with the mobility tag I know that you can search it up when you create a regex like this:

```
<situation xsi:type="management"(?:(?!</situation>).)+<mobility>([^\"]*)</mobility>
```

What changes do need to be made with the regex above to search for situations without the mobility child tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `<mobility>` tag optional:

```
<situation xsi:type="management"(?:(?!</situation>).)+(?:<mobility>([^\"]*?)</mobility>)?
```

---

If you want to match `<situation>` tag that doesn't contain `<mobility>` tag, use:

```
<situation xsi:type="management"(?:(?!</situation>)(?!<mobility>).)+</situation>
```

Comment: I want to search situations without this mobility tag. So only give results of situations which does not have this tag